# How should I use Flux.publish()?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Flux of data that I want to transform both in images and in reports. Because I want to reuse the same source of data, I thought of using the`publish` method on `Flux` and concatenate the results like in the code below:

```
    @Test
    fun `inside a publish, I can concat multiple fluxes`() {
        data class Data(val d: String)
        data class Image(val i: String)
        data class Report(val r: String)

        val result = Flux.just(Data("some data"))
                .publish { fluxOfData ->
                    val fod = fluxOfData  //.cache()
                    val images = fod.flatMap { Flux.just(Image("my image")) }
                    val reports = fod.flatMap { Flux.just(Report("my report")) }

                    Flux.concat(images, reports)
                }
                .collectList()
                .block()

        Assertions.assertEquals(result, listOf(Image("my image"), Report("my report")))
    }
```

However, the above code only sends `[Image(i=my image)]` so it's like the fluxOfData is consumed the first time. However I expected that I would be able to subscribe to `fluxOfData` multiple times.

When caching the `fluxOfData` by calling `fluxOfData.cache()`, the results come out as expected.

So what's the use case of `Flux.publish()`?
Is there another idiomatic way to transform the data into both images and reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`publish()` turns the `Flux` into a hot source (rather than a cold source). This means that multiple subscribers can subscribe at any time and see all elements going forward, but they'll miss all elements emitted beforehand.

> So what's the use case of Flux.publish()?

There's plenty of use cases for this - perhaps it's a stream of log messages that are being consumed somehow (and you're only interested in log messages that pop up in real-time, not previous logs.) Perhaps it's a "live update" stream covering a sports match. Perhaps it's a chat room.

> When caching the fluxOfData by calling fluxOfData.cache(), the results come out as expected.

Yup, because then you're explicitly caching all the signals emitted, so despite being a hot source, new subscribers can still be replayed all the existing elements in the stream.

> Is there another idiomatic way to transform the data into both images and reports?

Consider [`replay()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#replay--) instead of `publish()`:

> Turn this Flux into a hot source and cache last emitted signals for further Subscriber. Will retain an unbounded amount of onNext signals. Completion and Error will also be replayed.

In a more general sense, [this](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold) would also be good background reading.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I changed the implementation to .replay().autoConnect().